# Listing unique values formula taking a long time to process

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a formula from a previous question that's working fine. It lists the unique values of dynamic column A to column B, starting from B2. Often Column A has several thousand values, then the processing takes a long time. Increasing calculation threads hasn't saved much time. I'm looking for a better method or formula that could save me a lot of time.

`=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A;AGGREGATE(15;6;ROW($A$2:INDEX(A:A;MATCH("zzz";A:A)))/(COUNTIF($B$1:B1;$A$2:INDEX(A:A;MATCH("zzz";A:A)))=0);1));"")`

[image]

Comment: If you have access to it through the Office Insiders program, you could use [`UNIQUE`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/unique-function-c5ab87fd-30a3-4ce9-9d1a-40204fb85e1e). Otherwise VBA might be faster. Or just remove dupes?

Comment: A pivot table? Power Query? Or indeed VBA....

Comment: Advanced Filter?

Comment: @JvdV I created a pivot table, the calculation time is  probably 10 times faster now. Only downside, it requires clicking on the refresh button to update the Pivot Table. I can live with that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments to your question, using the new, "pre-official" UNIQUE function or a pivot table may be the easiest and fastest way to get the unique values. However, if you would like to use a VBA function that does not require pressing a button or using a newer version of Excel, you may want to try the VBA function "GetUniques" described below.

This is a sample of how the function could be used:

[image: Description of ArrayList at excelmacromastery.com]

To use the function, one must do 3 things:

1. Add a reference to mscorlib.dll in the VBA Editor (reason explained below)
2. Add the code for the VBA function itself (preferably in a module of its own)
3. Add code to handle the workbook's SheetCalculate event (reason explained below)

The reason for the mscorlib.dll was to use the "`ArrayList`" class (which made life easier than using the `Collection` class) because it comes with a sorting method (otherwise, we would have to implement a QuickSort procedure). To avoid late binding, I added the reference to this library (located at "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319" on my machine) in the VBA Editor. You may want to go to the link below for more info on how to use this class:

[https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-arraylist/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAbcq.png)

The VBA function actually writes values outside of the formula cell from which it is called. Since Excel does not take too well to this, a workaround was needed. I tried to use the "`Application.Evaluate`" method as a workaround, which is suggested in various places, but it did not work for me for some reason. Therefore, I was forced to use the SheetCalculate event (as recommended in other places). In short, the function itself does not write values outside of the caller cell but leaves a "request" for it in a "quasi-queue" that is then processed whilst Excel handles the SheetCalculate event; this event will be triggered after the VBA function has finished executing. This function writes the first value within the formula cell itself and the rest of the values directly below the formula cell.

The "GetUniques" function takes two arguments:

1. The range with the values to process (I recommend sending the entire column as the range, unless there is a header)
2. An **optional** "data type" string that allows the function to convert the values to the right data type (to avoid errors when comparing values of different types)

The optional "data type" value can be "L" (meaning "long integers"), "D" (meaning "dates"), "F" (meaning floating-point doubles), "S" (meaning case-insensitive strings), or "S2" (meaning "case-sensitive strings"). Values that cannot be converted will simply be ignored. If no "data type" value is provided, no type conversion is attempted, but the function may error out if an invalid comparison between different data types is attempted.

The code for the VBA function, called "GetUniques", appears below. This code can be copy-pasted to a module of its own:

```
Option Explicit

'This is the "commands queue" that is filled up in this module and is "executed" during the SheetCalculate event
Public ExtraCalcCommands As New Collection

Function GetUniques(ByVal dataRange As Range, Optional ByVal dataType As String = "") As Variant
  'Attempt to remove unused cells from the data range to make it smaller
  Dim dataRng As Range
  Set dataRng = Application.Intersect(dataRange, dataRange.Worksheet.UsedRange)

  'If the range is completely empty, simply exit
  If dataRng Is Nothing Then
    GetUniques = ""
    Exit Function
  End If

  'Read in all the data values from the range
  Dim values As Variant: values = dataRng.value

  'If the values do not form an array, it is a single value, so just return it
  If Not IsArray(values) Then
    GetUniques = values
    Exit Function
  End If

  'Get the 2-dimensional array's bounds
  Dim arrLb As Long: arrLb = LBound(values, 1)
  Dim arrUb As Long: arrUb = UBound(values, 1)
  Dim index2 As Long: index2 = LBound(values, 2) 'In the 2nd dimension, we only
                                                 '  care about the first column

  'Remember the original number of values
  Dim arrCount As Long: arrCount = arrUb - arrLb + 1
  'Since [values] is an array, we know that arrCount >= 2

  Dim i As Long

  'Using ArrayList based on ideas from https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-arraylist

  'Copy the values to an ArrayList object, discarding blank values and values
  '  that cannot be converted to the desired data type (if one was specified)
  Dim valuesList As New ArrayList
  Dim arrValue As Variant
  For i = arrLb To arrUb
    arrValue = values(i, index2)

    If (arrValue & "") = "" Then
      'Skip blank values
    ElseIf Not CouldConvert(arrValue, dataType) Then
      'This conversion may be necessary to ensure that the values can be compared against each other during the sort
    Else
      valuesList.Add arrValue
    End If
  Next

  Dim valuesCount As Long: valuesCount = valuesList.Count

  'Sort the list to easily remove adjacent duplicates
  If Not CouldSort(valuesList) Then
    GetUniques = "#ERROR: Could not sort - consider using the data type argument"
    Exit Function
  End If

  'Remove duplicates (which are now adjacent due to the sort)
  Dim previous As Variant
  If valuesCount > 0 Then previous = valuesList.Item(0)
  Dim current As Variant
  i = 1
  Do While i < valuesCount
    current = valuesList.Item(i)

    If ValuesMatch(current, previous, dataType) Then 'Remove duplicates
      valuesList.RemoveAt i
      valuesCount = valuesCount - 1
    Else
      previous = current
      i = i + 1
    End If
  Loop

  'Replace the removed items with empty strings at the end of the list
  '  This is to get back to the original number of values
  For i = 1 To arrCount - valuesCount
    valuesList.Add ""
  Next

  'Return the first value as the function result
  GetUniques = valuesList.Item(0) 'We know valuesList.Count=arrCount>=2

  'Write the rest of the values below
  valuesList.RemoveAt 0
  WriteArrayTo valuesList, Application.Caller.Offset(1, 0)
End Function

Private Function CouldSort(ByRef valuesList As ArrayList)
  On Error Resume Next
  valuesList.Sort
  CouldSort = Err.Number = 0
End Function

Private Function CouldConvert(ByRef value As Variant, ByVal dataType As String)
  CouldConvert = True

  If dataType = "" Then Exit Function

  On Error Resume Next
  Select Case dataType
    Case "L": value = CLng(value)
    Case "F": value = CDbl(value)
    Case "D": value = CDate(value)
    Case "S", "S2": value = value & ""
  End Select

  CouldConvert = Err.Number = 0
End Function

Private Function ValuesMatch(ByVal v1 As Variant, ByVal v2 As Variant, ByVal dataType As String) As Boolean
  On Error Resume Next
  Select Case dataType
    Case "S": ValuesMatch = StrComp(v1, v2, vbTextCompare) = 0
    Case "S2": ValuesMatch = StrComp(v1, v2, vbBinaryCompare) = 0
    Case Else: ValuesMatch = v1 = v2
  End Select
  If Err.Number <> 0 Then ValuesMatch = False
End Function

Private Sub WriteArrayTo(ByVal list As ArrayList, ByRef destination As Range)
  'This procedure does not do the actual writing but saves the "command" to do the writing in a "queue";
  '  this "commands queue" will be executed in the SheetCalculate event;
  'We cannot write to cells outside the UDF's formula whilst the function is being calculated
  '  because of Excel restrictions; that is why we must postpone the writing for later

  Dim coll As New Collection
  coll.Add "DoWriteList" 'Name of the procedure to execute
  coll.Add destination   '1st argument used by the procedure
  coll.Add list          '2nd argument used by the procedure
  ExtraCalcCommands.Add coll
End Sub
```

This code must be added in the workbook's "ThisWorkbook" module in order to handle the SheetCalculate event:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetCalculate(ByVal Sh As Object)
  Dim i&
  Do While ExtraCalcCommands.Count > 0
    Dim cmdColl As Collection: Set cmdColl = ExtraCalcCommands.Item(1)
    Select Case cmdColl.Item(1)
      Case "DoWriteList": DoWriteList cmdColl.Item(2), cmdColl.Item(3)
      'Other procedure names could go here in future
    End Select

    'Remove the processed "command" from the queue
    ExtraCalcCommands.Remove 1
  Loop
End Sub

Private Sub DoWriteList(ByRef destination As Range, ByVal list As ArrayList)
  destination.Resize(list.Count, 1).value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(list.ToArray)
End Sub
```

I hope the above is of some help, and, if so, I hope it is a speed improvement on the original IFERROR formula. I also hope the SheetCalculate event handler does not pose issues in dense workbooks with many formulas and calculations.